how can i extract numbered lists,bullets and alignment of content if docx file using python docx
I can extract the contents of a DOCX file using Python's python-docx, and I am generating an HTML file from the extracted content. However, I'm struggling to ensure that the contents are properly aligned, and I am also having difficulty extracting numbered lists, bullets, and styles correctly. My current code is functioning well, and I will paste it below. Please assist me in figuring out how to properly extract numbered lists, bullets, and apply styles while creating the HTML. Although I can extract the styles, they are not applied correctly in the generated HTML. My main issues lie with the handling of numbered lists and bullets and alignment of text
Code :

from docx.oxml.ns import qn
import json
import re
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P


def extract_elements(docx_file):
    """Extract all paragraphs and tables in the order they appear."""
    document = Document(docx_file)
    elements = []

    for child in document.element.body:
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):  # If it's a paragraph
            paragraph_data = _get_paragraph(child, document)
            if paragraph_data:
                elements.append(paragraph_data)

        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):  # If it's a table
            table_data = _get_table(child, document)
            if table_data:
                elements.append({"type": "table", "data": table_data})

    return elements



def _get_paragraph(element, document):
    """Extract paragraph text, bullet/numbering style, and format."""
    try:
        # Find the matching paragraph in the document by element reference
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            if paragraph._element == element:
                text = paragraph.text.strip()
                alignment = _get_alignment(paragraph)  # Get paragraph alignment
                numbered_list = _get_numbered_list(paragraph)  # Detect numbered list

                return {
                    "type": "paragraph",
                    "text": text,
                    "style": paragraph.style.name if paragraph.style else "",
                    "alignment": alignment,
                    "numberedlist": numbered_list,
                }

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in _get_paragraph: {e}")
    return None


def _get_alignment(paragraph):
    """Get alignment of the paragraph."""
    alignment_map = {0: "left", 1: "center", 2: "right", 3: "justify"}
    return alignment_map.get(paragraph.alignment, "left")  # Default to left alignment


def _get_numbered_list(paragraph):
    """Detect whether the paragraph has a bullet/numbered style and retrieve its details."""
    try:
        # Access the XML element directly
        p = paragraph._element

        # Print the entire XML of the paragraph for debugging
        # print(p.xml)
        xml_content = p.xml

        # Append the XML content to the file
        with open("D://newxml.xml", "a", encoding="utf-8") as xml_file:
            # Optional: Add a separator between paragraphs for clarity
            xml_file.write(f"\n<!-- New Paragraph -->\n{xml_content}\n")

        # Accessing the paragraph properties
        pPr = p.find(qn("w:pPr"))

        if pPr is not None:
            # Try to find numPr in the paragraph properties
            numPr = pPr.find(qn("w:numPr"))
            print(f"numPr found: {numPr is not None}")  # Debugging output

            if numPr is not None:
                numId = numPr.find(qn("w:numId"))
                ilvl = numPr.find(qn("w:ilvl"))

                if numId is not None and ilvl is not None:
                    numId_val = numId.get(qn("w:val"))
                    ilvl_val = ilvl.get(qn("w:val"))
                    return _get_number_format(paragraph.part, numId_val, ilvl_val)
            else:
                print("numPr is None, check paragraph properties.")
        else:
            print("pPr is None, check paragraph element.")

        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in _get_bullet_style: {e}")
    return None


def _get_number_format(doc_part, numId, ilvl):
    """Retrieve the numbering format from the DOCX numbering part."""
    try:
        numbering_part = doc_part.numbering_part  # Access numbering definitions
        xpath = f".//w:num[@w:numId='{numId}']//w:abstractNumId"
        abstract_num = numbering_part.element.xpath(xpath)

        if abstract_num:
            abstract_num_id = abstract_num[0].get(qn("w:val"))
            level_xpath = f".//w:abstractNum[@w:abstractNumId='{abstract_num_id}']//w:lvl[@w:ilvl='{ilvl}']//w:numFmt"
            num_fmt = numbering_part.element.xpath(level_xpath)

            if num_fmt:
                return {
                    "numId": numId,
                    "level": int(ilvl),
                    "format": num_fmt[0].get(qn("w:val")),
                }
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in _get_number_format: {e}")


def _get_table(element, document):
    """Extract table data ensuring correct structure."""
    for table in document.tables:
        if table._element == element:
            return _extract_table_content(table)
    return None


def _extract_table_content(table):
    """Ensure correct table row and column consistency."""
    rows = []
    max_cols = max(len(row.cells) for row in table.rows)  # Get the max columns
    for row in table.rows:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.cells:
            cell_text = cell.text.strip()

            # Avoid appending duplicate content in the same row
            if cell_text not in row_data:
                row_data.append(cell_text)

        # Ensure row has consistent number of columns
        while len(row_data) < max_cols:
            row_data.append("")  # Pad missing cells with empty strings

        rows.append(row_data)

    return rows


def save_elements_to_json(elements, file_path):
    """Save extracted elements to a JSON file."""
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(elements, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


def save_elements_to_html(elements, file_path):
    """Convert extracted elements to properly aligned HTML."""
    html_content = "<html><body>"
    in_list = False  # Track whether we are in a list
    in_toc_table = False  # Track if we're inside a TOC table
    list_type = ""  # Keep track of the list type (decimal, lowerLetter, upperLetter)

    for element in elements:
        if element["type"] == "paragraph":
            numbered_list = element.get("numberedlist")  # Safely get 'numbered_list'

            # Handle TOC entries
            if element["style"] == "toc 1":
                if not in_toc_table:
                    # Start a new TOC table
                    html_content += '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">'
                    html_content += (
                        "<tr><th>Clause</th><th>Heading</th><th>Page</th></tr>"
                    )
                    in_toc_table = True  # Mark that we are inside the TOC table

                # Split the text by tabs and add as a row in the table
                row_data = element["text"].split("\t")
                html_content += "<tr>"
                for cell in row_data:
                    html_content += (
                        f'<td style="padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;">{cell}</td>'
                    )
                html_content += "</tr>"
            else:
                # Close the TOC table if we encounter non-TOC content
                if in_toc_table:
                    html_content += "</table>"
                    in_toc_table = False

                # Handle numbered/bullet list
                if numbered_list:  # Check if the paragraph belongs to a list
                    if not in_list:
                        # Set the list type based on the numbering format
                        list_format = numbered_list["format"]
                        if list_format == "decimal":
                            list_type = "1"  # Decimal list
                        elif list_format == "lowerLetter":
                            list_type = "a"  # Lowercase letters
                        elif list_format == "upperLetter":
                            list_type = "A"  # Uppercase letters
                        else:
                            list_type = ""  # Default case

                        html_content += f'<ol style="list-style-type: {list_type};">'  # Start a new ordered list
                        in_list = True

                    # Indent the list item based on its level
                    indent = numbered_list["level"] * 20
                    html_content += (
                        f'<li style="margin-left: {indent}px;">'
                        f'{element["text"]}</li>'
                    )
                else:  # Handle non-list paragraphs
                    if in_list:
                        html_content += "</ol>"  # Close the list if we were in one
                        in_list = False

                    # Render the paragraph with alignment
                    alignment = element.get(
                        "alignment", "left"
                    )  # Default to 'left' if missing
                    style = element.get(
                        "style", "Normal"
                    )  # Default style if not available
                    html_content += (
                        f'<p style="text-align: {alignment}; font-family: {style};">'
                        f'{element["text"]}</p>'
                    )

        elif element["type"] == "table":
            # Close any open list before starting a new table
            if in_list:
                html_content += "</ol>"
                in_list = False

            # Render table content
            html_content += (
                '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">'
            )
            for row in element["data"]:
                html_content += "<tr>"
                for cell in row:
                    html_content += (
                        f'<td style="padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #ddd;">{cell}</td>'
                    )
                html_content += "</tr>"
            html_content += "</table>"

    # Close any remaining open list or table
    if in_list:
        html_content += "</ol>"
    if in_toc_table:
        html_content += "</table>"

    html_content += "</body></html>"

    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(html_content)




        
if __name__ == "__main__":


 docx_file = "/Services Agreement.docx"
 elements = extract_elements(docx_file)
 save_elements_to_json(elements, "D://extracted_content.json")
 save_elements_to_html(elements, "D://extracted_content.html")


I am expecting to extract the numberedlists,bullets and styles properly
